# Deleting log files from VirtualBox

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I created a virtual machine in VirtualBox, which will be used by other people.

In the VirtualBoxVMs-Folder, I found a folder called "Logs". There I can see three files: VBox.log, VBox.log.1 and VBoxHardening.log. There are some information stored about my private host pc (some IDs, Windows Version, Stats etc.).

Since I don't understand all of these logs and what could be done with it, I would just like to delete the whole log folder. Can I just do that, or would it result in performance problems for the virtual machine's users?

Answer (score 3):

Removing logs should not affect the performance of VMs in anyway whatsover.

Here is an article about VM logs location and details: https://blogs.oracle.com/scoter/virtualbox-log-files-v2

Quoting from above article:

One of the key tools you can use to diagnose any issues with VirtualBox is the VirtualBox log file for a vm session. VirtualBox always creates a log file which reflects the lifecycle of the virtual machine.

VirtualBox log files live in a per-user/per-vm standard directory that will be something like:

On Windows, this is `"%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%\\.VirtualBox\\Machines\\<vm name>\\Logs"`; typically some- thing like `"C:\\Users\\Username\\.VirtualBox\\Machines\\<vm name>\\Logs\\vbox.log"`

On Mac OS X, this is `"$HOME/VirtualBox/Machines/<vm name>/Logs"`
On Unix-like systems (Linux, Solaris), this is `"$HOME/.VirtualBox/Machines/<vm name>/Logs"`

The log files are rotated such that the most recent is always called vbox.log and older ones are vbox.log.[123]. These log files contain lots of information about the capabilities of both the host and the guest vm and should be provided whenever reporting issues with VirtualBox.

Comment: Use this variable `%USERPROFILE%`.

Comment: Link provided is dead by now - however this is the only reference on all the internet I've found about vbox.log.1, vbox.log.2 and vbox.log.3.... thank you